# External login callback signs incorrect user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, shopify

I have a strange problem with `ExternalLoginCallback` method. I am logging some information in the log and what is interesting `Email` is correct, but then `userId` is incorrect and it belongs to another user who was logged previously.

I.e. some `UserA` is logged into the system and now `UserB` wants to log into the system in `another` window. I am expecting that in new window `UserB` will be logged in and overwrite cookies, so if I refresh first window it will show `UserB`, but somehow that is not happening and in second window it shows `UserA`.

Here is the code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (loginInfo == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }

    EventLogManager.LogWarning(loginInfo.Email);

    var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: true);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            {
                var userId = SignInManager.AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Identity.GetUserId();

                EventLogManager.LogWarning(userId);
                ...
```

**EDIT**

I think I should add more clarifications. There is some action which is being called from third party - `Shopify`. It looks like:

```
public ActionResult Callback(string code, string hmac, string shop, string state, string timestamp)
{
    //this resolved the issue
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    Session["Workaround"] = 0;

    return new ChallengeResult("Shopify", Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = "/Product/Products" }), null, shop.Replace(".myshopify.com", ""));
}
```

Comment: Whats your logout method look like?  It should be removing the cookies

Comment: @DaImTo, its standard. I didn't change it. How this can be related? Also if I logoff issue is resolved, but I was expecting this behavior without logging off prev user. 
 `AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["current_token"] = null;
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["current_shop"] = null;

            return RedirectToAction("Welcome", "Home");`

Comment: @DaImTo, actually I didn't explain the whole thing. I am not using standard login procudure. I am calling ChallengeResult manually. So there is an action which is being called by third party, in that action I am calling ChallengeResult.